# 'function' object has no attribute 'fft2' error scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I am struggling with an error called 'function' object has no attribute 'fft2'. First of all,
I have imported the following:
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import fft
After executing the following block of code in jupyter notebook:

```
gainDisplay=1
InImgFFT=fft.fft2(InImg,norm="ortho")
InImgAmplSpec=np.abs(fft.fftshift(InImgFFT))
plt.figure(figsize=(W/DPI+1,H/DPI+1))
plt.imshow(np.clip(InImgAmplSpec*gainDisplay,0,255),cmap = 'rainbow')
plt.suptitle('The amplitude spectrum of the gray scale input image')
plt.show()
```

I get the error mentioned at the line with fft.fft2() function

[image]

Could you please help me to solve this error?
scipy version is 1.5.2

Another mention would be that I have a conda environment where i have installed all the packets, but I hope that won't be a problem.

Comment: Did you try to use `from scipy.fft import fft2` and `InImgFFT = fft2(...)`?

Comment: The problem is probably than you have the function `scipy.fft.fft` as variable `fft`. You can also just try to import the `fft` again with `from scipy import fft`. Make sure you don't assign anything to variable `fft` before trying to call `fft.fft2()`.

Comment: I tried that too. Unfortunately I get this error when I import that: No module named 'scipy.fft'

Comment: Maybe it could be the version of scipy. A classmate used the same lines of code and worked for him

Comment: I tried with scipy 1.5.2. and `from scipy import fft` works just fine. Can you confirm your scipy version by printing out `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`?.